# Encountering Instantiation error while configuring HikariCP

Tags: spring, connection-pooling, hikaricp

Hi all i'm new to connection pooling.Before HikariCP i used DBCP for connection pooling. But since HikariCP is new and faster i thought of implementing the same in my project, but encountering below error while config HikarCP in spring.Pls help me overcome this.Thank You.

Error

Instantiation of bean failed:nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInitializerError

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
<artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
<version>1.7.5</version>
<optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
<artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
<version>3.18.1-GA</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

context.xml

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
<property name="driverClassName"  
value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
<property name="URL" value="<url goes here>" />
<property name="user" value="abc"/>
<property name="password" value="xyz"/>
<property name="implicitCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-
method="close">                          
<constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />  
</bean>
```

Comment: HikariCP v1.3.0 is ancient, try v2.6.0.

Comment: hi...even with v2.6.0 getting same error.Thank you

Comment: You are specifying a DataSource class name as a driver class name.  They are different.